# Turning a C++ program with iterators into a Boost MPI parallel program

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm having a hard time thinking how I can turn my program into a parallel one (I never did this before). Basically, I have a dataset (it's a vector of objects) and I extract a group of clusters from them, where each cluster have a vector of iterators, and each iterator points to the original place on the dataset.

What I want to do is make the process of creating clusters parallel, and then send all the clusters back to the main thread. The problem is that I'm using boost to serialize everything and send it through MPI, and it doesn't serialize iterators. I thought of simply using pointers to the dataset instead of iterators, but them I would need to do something so that, when the clusters are sent back to the main thread, the main thread makes every pointer to a newly created object point to the dataset vector instead (and then delete the old objects), and I don't think that's a really good solution, and I can't think of a fast way to do this too.

That's just the first part, after that I will need to send again the clusters to the threads so they can do some other calculations, so the process of gathering the clusters shouldn't be too slow.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you mean MPI, not OpenMP? Are you wanting to use multiple threads on a single, multi-core computer or multiple processes on multiple computers linked together?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I thought I was going to be notified by email. It's MPI, with multiple computers. Not sure if it was the best for the project, but sadly I need to stick with it now. I solved the problem now, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution sometime ago, and the answer was really simple. The problem was that the partitions have a vector of clusters, and the clusters have a vector with pointers do the dataset objects, and so I couldn't send partitions to other processors. The solution was to simple create another simple way to represent a partition by a integer array. For that I create an int array with the size of the dataset, and inside each position of the array I put the index of the cluster which it belongs to. So, if the object 10 belongs to the cluster of index 3 on the cluster array of the partition, I put 3 on position 10. Now I simply send the dataset and this array and recreate the cluster at the other side if necessary (I can do that because each object is only on one cluster).

This solutions is kind of obvious (not sure how I didn't think about it before) and I doubt this specific solution will help anyone else, but maybe it will help someone else realize that you can represent the data on other simpler ways just for sending via MPI when serialization doesn't work.